# How to create a promptless Linux GUI shutdown script?

Tags: shutdown

I want to shutdown my Linux system using a script from GUI:

```
shutdown.sh
#!/bin/bash
init 0
```

This script asks me a question.

I need a shutdown script without asking any question.

Note that my GUI login is `root` user.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the output when running this script?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already root, then you can call

```
shutdown -h now
```

and the system will go down right away with no confirmation needed.

Answer (score 0):

For doing `init 0` you will need root rights. Using DBUS to send the shutdown signal circumvents this:

`dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement.Shutdown`

Put this line in your script and it should work.